# Monitor if a running X session is idle for a while

Tags: command-line, xorg, xfce

Is there any way to monitor if a X session is inactive for i.e 10 minutes? And I would execute a command when it happens, like a screensaver, but it's not a screensaver in this case.

Answer (score 2):

For gnome-screensaver, check out this [page](http://blog.troyastle.com/2011/06/run-scripts-when-gnome-screensaver.html). He has a python script which hooks up to the screensaver events to run commands.

Also [xscreensaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man3.html) has an option you can use in a script to react to screensaver events (look for -watch option)

Set the screensaver to do nothing on activation if you don't actually want the screensaver to kick in, and you're done.